# What is the difference between readdir and opendir in FUSE

Tags: fuse

In the [libfuse documentation](https://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html) there are both `readdir` and `opendir` as defined operations.

From what I have found, `readdir` is the one which will list out the contents of a directory. If so, what is the function of `opendir`? The documentation states that this opens the directory but what does opening a directory actually mean if it is not simply listing its content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*opendir* doesn't do any listing. It's purpose is to open a file handle, which is the interface on which the listing can be done using *readdir*. It does the checking of the existence of the directory path, whether the caller has permissions to open, etc and so it might return an error in case it's not possible to do the listing.

The handle provided by *opendir* serves as a listing state context - it holds the current listing offset and it can be manipulated to be rewinded or to jump ahead forward using *seek*.

The relation between the two corresponds to *open* and *read*. In addition, these Fuse functions implement the real OS functions:

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-a-Directory.html

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reading_002fClosing-Directory.html